# pause/play ffmp3 with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There is an Open Source mp3 player that is flash based. I was wondering if anyone knew how to pause and play it using javascript.

Here is a working example of it, but I can't necessarily figure out how it is being done.
http://sightofnick.com/public/ffmp3/test-skin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the player:

```
<object id="theIdOfThePlayer" ...>
...
<embed name="theIdOfThePlayer">
...
```

Get the player like this:

```
var player=(document.theIdOfThePlayer) ? document.theIdOfThePlayer : document.getElementById('theIdOfThePlayer');
```

Pause like this:

```
player.stopSound();
```

Start like this:

```
player.playSound();
```

Comment: but it keeps say `TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'playSound'`

Comment: it still isn't working, check out the page im trying to get it working on: http://sightofnick.com/public/piff/

Comment: You have a typo in `?document.player_moudle:`. It should be `?document.player_module:`